# Cloud Datastore - Will deleting an inexistent entity in datastore cause an error?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

Does deleting an entity that no longer exists in the datastore cause an error? Or does it silently return?

I am wondering what would happen if I was bulk deleting a large number of entities and during that processes, some of them may have been deleted by other means, if that would cause an error and the bulk delete operation to stop.

Comment: That should be easy to just try - just bulk delete a few entities one or two of which you already deleted through the admin console... ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not cause an error. Deleting a nonexistent entity has no effect.